# How to hint type inference when using static imports?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, hamcrest

I am using junit with hamcrest in my unit tests and I came across a generics problem:

```
assertThat(collection, empty());
```

I am aware of type inference not being available this way and that one of the solutions is to give a type hint, but how should I type hint when using static imports?

Comment: Don't think you can. Do `MyUtility.<MyType>empty()`.

Comment: @rodion I guess you are right, I hate how Java featrues don't play along each other. BTW. the empty() method is part of the hamcrest library of matchers (not included in JUnit).

Comment: It's a bit of a shame, isn't it. Sometimes, if I need to use a matcher like `empty()` multiple times, I just create a private method bound to specific type, like `private static Matcher<MyType> empty(){ return IsEmptyCollection.empty() }`. Can make your tests a little more readable in the long run:)

Comment: @rodion - Rewrite your comments as an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While type inference is not as powerful as we would like, in this case, it's really the API that's at fault. It unnecessarily restricts itself for no good reason. The is-empty matcher works on any collection, not just on collections of a specific `E`.

Suppose the API is designed this way

```
public class IsEmptyCollection implements Matcher<Collection<?>>
{
    public static Matcher<Collection<?>> empty()
    {
        return new IsEmptyCollection();
    }
}
```

then `assertThat(list, empty())` works as expected.

You can try to convince the author to change the API. Meanwhile you can have a wrapper

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Matcher<Collection<?>> my_empty()
{
    return (Matcher<Collection<?>>)IsEmptyCollection.empty();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this trade-off similar to Collections.emptyList() vs. Collections.EMPTY_LIST in java.util? If not, why then Collections.emptyList() uses concrete type parameter as opposed to wildcard you suggest?

Comment: our empty() here returns a verb, we want it as general as possible so it can work on more objects. Collections.emptyList() returns a noun, it should be as specific as possible to satisfy caller's need. An empty list of String is not the same as an empty list of Integer.

Comment: "try to convince the author to change the API" -- indeed, there is already this issue: http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=97 as well as a few others addressing more or less the same type of problem. There are some good patches there as well, to give you an idea of how you might write your own versions of their matchers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the problem. Here's the method I use:

```
/**
 * A matcher that returns true if the supplied {@link Iterable} is empty.
 */
public static Matcher<Iterable<?>> isEmpty() {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<Iterable<?>>() {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("empty");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(final Iterable<?> item) {
            return item != null && !item.iterator().hasNext();
        }
    };
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
assertThat(list, isEmpty());
```

No problem with generics here.

Comment: I was using part of the hamcrest framework: http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/collection/IsEmptyCollection.java

Comment: @Gabriel I see. I only know the Hamcrest library bundled with JUnit, which doesn't include that class.

Comment: I did as well until I found myself often using org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers and writing simple and similar matchers at my own - I looked into hamcrest and it is full of nice matchers, except this one.